# Does the relation $\exp(\log T)=T(\|T-I\|<1)$ hold in a Banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis

In real analysis of one variable, we have , $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\log(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^n}{n}(|x|<1).$

In case of Banach space $E$ and for a bounded linear operator $T$ we can similarly define,
$\log(I+T)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}T^n}{n}(||T||<1)$ and $\exp(T)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{T^n}{n!}.$

Now my question is that, does the relation $\exp(\log T)=T(||T-I||<1)$ hold in this case?

I know it's true, when $T\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ but my question is for any banach space $E$

Comment: It does hold in general (under the condition $\lVert T - I\rVert < 1$ of course). We have absolute convergence, hence you can reorder the nested power series and at the end reach $I + (T-I) = T$.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Actually there are lots of terms to handle. I guessed that we need to use the absolute convergence but I am not convinced yet, can you expand your comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done right away using Holomorphic Functional Calculus. On a disk of radius less than $1$, centered at $0$, your function $z\longmapsto \log(1+z)$ is analytic. From $1+z=\exp(\log(1+z))$ on such a disk, using that the functional calculus is a homomorphism we get
$$
I+T=\exp(\log(I+T)),\qquad \|T\|<1.
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer.But, I didn't get one point.How are you using complex numbers in operators?Can you elaborate?Any reference?

Comment: Functional Calculus is big deal in Operator Algebras, be it Banach Algebras, or C*-algebras, or von Neumann algebras. For the Banach Algebra version, you can look for instance at 10.21 in Rudin's *Functional Analysis*, or Section VII.4 in Conway's *A Course in Functional Analysis*.

Comment: Thank you. Can you elaborate the term "Functional Calculus is a homomorphism"?

Comment: Probably not the best expression to use in that situation. But the point is that the map $f\longmapsto f(T)$ respects addition, multiplication, and composition. So in particular $(f\circ g)(T)=f(g(T))$.